# Cannot assign value of type Login to type XMLParserDelegate

Tags: ios, swift

I put this function in a class and I don't understand this error.

My Code:

[image: Code]

Can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: where u write this code with error

Comment: Put code as code not as picture please.

Comment: Please elaborate your question and also one suggestion  NSURLConnection class should no longer be used.  NSURLSession is the replacement for NSURLConnection

Comment: Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the delegation of your XMLParser to your class which does not conform to the protocol.

Your class *Login* should implement the XMLParserDelegate protocol :

```
extension Login: XMLParserDelegate{

}
```

I suggest you to read this : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID276

And to google around "swift delegation", there are a lot of good example that explain this concept